# How to extract the data from MS-excel before and after a pattern .

Tags: regex, excel, extract, formula

I have a table with column A filled with data in below format . I need help in extracting the data before and after a pattern .
I have marked un-patterned data in bold and italic.
I have marked patterned data in regular font.

Data in cells of Column A:
SR ***1-2345678912***: (ABC Company) M@M ***Interested in this part***

Output expected in Column B :
 1-2345678912

Output expected in Column C :
 Interested in this part

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @GalAbra I am currently using three functions .  (1) =LEFT(A1, SEARCH(": (ABC Company) M@M",A1,1)-1)         This gives me **SR 1-2345678912**  (2) =REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("M@M",A1,1)+2,"")       this gives me  **Interested in this part**   (3) Again I Run =REPLACE(B1,1,FIND(" ",B1,1),"")   on the results of step 1 to get **1-2345678912**

Comment: I wanted to know if it is the efficient way of doing it .

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query. Put your source data in a table / named range, then assuming your input structure is actually consistent with the ONE example you've provided, you can use something like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyData"]}[Content],
    #"Inserted Output B" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Output B", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1], " ", ":"), type text),
    #"Inserted Output C" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Output B", "Output C", each Text.AfterDelimiter(Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1], "@")," "), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Output C",{"Column1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```